# No connection string named 'SPOEntities' could be found in the application config file.'

Tags: c#, .net

ive started a new solution within my project
i added the connection string to the app.config file
and still gets this error, ive tried also to set it as my startup project.
any ideas?
my app.config:

Comment: You'll have to provide us with your app.config file, or we will not be able to help you.

Comment: If you add some of your code it would help figure things out. Example of the app.config setting and where you are referencing it in your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Asaf Ben Shabat. Please provide more information. Can you post the app.config file ? Do you call your connection string from a referenced dll ?

Comment: here is my app.config file - https://pastebin.com/t8jbbSdJ